# Preenchimento de planilha VBA

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Preciso que o código preencha uma planilha com várias colunas e linhas, porém quando coloco mais de uma linha na programação, ele só corresponde a última linha que digitei

Exemplo:
ActiveSheet.Range(V7:V12).Offset (0,1).Select
ActiveSheet.Range(V27:V133).Offset (0,1).Select

Nesse caso ele só iria dar o resultado da última linha.

Preciso que o código entenda o intervalo entre as linhas

Código completo:

Sub FillCellsFromAbove

Turn of screen updating to improve performance

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
'look in Column V

With selection
ActiveSheet.Range(V7:V12).Offset (0,1).Select
Selection.Formula = "=5+2"
'Convert the Formula to a value
.Value = .Value
End with
Err.Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
End sub

Answer (score 0):

Olá. isso deve resolver seu problema:

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
    ActiveSheet.Range("V7:V12").FormulaR1C1 = "=5+2"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bom dia, obrigada isso me ajudou muito, se não for abusar eu preciso de ajuda pra inserir a soma SE nesse código: =SOMASES(Base!$D$2:$D$598:Base!$A$2$A$598;$C7;Base!$H$2:$H$598;$A7;Base!$B$2:B$598;V$3

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, recomendo fortemente a usar uma função e fazer o VBA inserir o valor já retornado pela função. Ficaria assim:

```
Sub somases()

'Declara as variáveis
Dim celulas As Object
Dim somases As Integer

'Laço que percorre as células do intervalo desejado e insere os valores calculados
For Each celulas In Range("V7:V12")
    somases = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Base").Range("D2:D598"), Sheets("Base").Range("A2:A598"), Sheets("Base").Range("C7"), _
        Sheets("Base").Range("H2:H598"), Sheets("Base").Range("A7"), Sheets("Base").Range("B2:B598"), Sheets("Base").Range("V3"))
    
    celulas.Value = somases
Next
End Sub
```

Desta forma o valor da célula será o valor calculado pela função, e não a formula em sí. Faz mais sentido, pois se for pra inserir a formula simplesmente pode inserir direto na célula sem VBA.

OBS: caso o resultado do SOMASES sejam números decimais a variável somases no código VBA deve ser declarada do tipo double.

```
dim somases as double
```

Espero ter ajudade, abraços!